# ABPersonCopyImageData on iOS4

Tags: iphone

the `ABPersonCopyImageData` function in iOS4 SDK 4.0->4.02 seems to return uncropped image
and leads to terrible performance and crashing due to running out of memory. It used
to work fine on OC versions 3.0->3.1.3. I've tried upgrading to 4.02 but still same issues

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now there is `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat` in the SDK 4.1 which returns either thumbnails or the full image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post. I had a major surprise bug due to this issue in a release and this post helped save the day with rapid bug fix.

Everything had previously worked fine but suddenly went all wrong with users who had contact images of a certain types. Setting the format to `kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail` completely solved the issue.